# How do people ride road bikes without fenders?

Tags: road-bike, winter

I want to buy a bike. The road bikes look very gorgeous. However I noticed that they come without fenders to protect from water! I was really surprised for that actually and that made me wonder about how do people protect themselves when driving on wet roads.

When one drives on a wet road then you get smashed by water and your clothes get dirty. So how do people protect themselves when driving a road bike?! Are the tires somehow made that they prevent water? Or what is the secret?!

Comment: See [Rule #9](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#9).

Comment: Since this does not qualify as an answer, adding as a comment. Road bikes use much more narrow tires which are often completely bald as well so that water is less likely to rotate together with the wheel. It is still flying around but much less than on MTB, for example.

Comment: @Rilakkuma - you still get soaked on a road bike if you ride without fenders. Bald tires still pickup plenty of water.   faster rotational speeds also picks up more water.

Comment: My 700x28's don't throw up nearly as much water as my 26x2.1's at around the same speed.

Comment: A rider of a road bike has the very straightforward mentality that if it rains, they will get wet. So what? Fenders add weight, road riders don't like that. And they'll only deflect a fraction of any rain. It's just a matter of priorities, no secrets involved

Comment: When it rains you get wet.  Fenders, and, to a lesser degree, details of bike geometry can make it a little better, but if you're out in the rain for an hour or so you will be wet through and through regardless.  (I have standard fenders on my touring bike, but racers sneer at them, and they're a handicap in mud or snow since they get clogged.)

Comment: If you're out in the rain you will get wet fenders or no, but where fenders really help is after the rain stops, when the road is still wet.

Comment: How do people ride road bikes without fenders?  They pedal.   What is the secrete when it rains?  They get wet.

Comment: If you can't Rule #9, see [Rule #5](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#5)

Comment: The consequences of getting wet vary a lot by location. Get caught in rain country in the middle of fields in a country where studded winter tires are used, and you'll find every crevice in the bike, piece of clothing and  body orifice full of mixture of wet dust and chewed up asphalt. Get caught in the middle of forest where studded tires are not used, and you are just sprayed with mostly clean water.

Comment: We're talking road bikes, remember. Let's try to stay on topic.

Comment: *"How do people ride road bikes without fenders?"* **FAST**

Comment: Over in Europe all commuter bikes I saw had fenders. Yes, when it rains you get wet; unless you have the sense to carry rain gear. And it is entirely different to be covered with mud and dirt! And the average rider is not soaked in sweat when he arrives at work.......Italian men wear three piece suits and you would never know they rode a bike to work! You dress one-way for competitive racing; another way for commuting.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "how do people ride without fenders", so it's likely to be deleted.

Comment: In the U.K. You can't guarantee staying dry even if you head out on a gorgeous sunny ride in the morning. Plus, you'll sweat through anyway so we just always plan to shower and get into clean clothes at the end of a ride. That simple.

Answer (score 27):

Most road bikes are the equivalent of an open-top racing car. You just don't ride them in the rain. And if you do, you are expected to be hard core enough that a little rain isn't worth the weight and aerodynamic drag that the fenders would cause. And there's also a reason that hardcore racers wear sunglasses during the day or transparent glasses in the evening -- they help keep bugs and rain out of your eyes. And as many people note, you'll be soaking wet from sweat anyway if you're riding hard.

That being said, there are some slim fenders that can attach to *some* road bikes -- although many/most road bikes currently being sold come without fender eyelets and are so aerodynamic that there isn't enough space between the wheel and forks/stays to put a fender that would work a darn. If you want fenders but like the road bike drop-bar style, look at expedition/touring bikes or cyclocross bikes.

Or, if you're like many people, you instead have a beater commuter with fenders that you ride in the rain and you keep your gorgeous carbon fiber racer for sunny days. One can never have [too many bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23853/when-do-i-need-more-than-one-bike-how-many-bike-is-enough-how-many-bikes-is-to?s=1%7C2.6924).

Comment: Surprisingly, nobody has mentioned [Rule #12](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#12). At least not for a week or two :-)

Comment: On most club and group rides in the Pacific Northwest (temperate rain forest) fenders and mudflaps are mandatory on every road bike.  Most also own a dedicated rain bike too (n + 1).   No fenders by late spring/summer. The no fenders threshold varies by region me thinks.

Comment: Of course people who have road bikes ride them in the rain!

Comment: You could buy an ass-saver but I'm not sure it's worth it. You should already be wet from sweat when in rains...

Answer (score 11):

You will get wet if you ride at speed on a wet road without fenders. I think you can find fenders to fit almost any road bike if you want them, but otherwise I can think a few things that mitigate the problem:

- Change clothes shortly after the end of the ride, and wash and dry yourself if facilities are available.
- Wear tight cycling clothes. You will still be wet, but you won't have the sensation of repeatedly touching wet fabric.
- Wear clothes made with fabrics designed not to hold much water and to dry quickly.
- Wear waterproof / water resistant clothing, ideally breathable to allow water vapour from sweat to escape.
- Put lots of energy into cycling. This will generate heat.

Comment: Without fenders, you'll get wet even if you don't ride at speed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby at speed, your trip is shorter so less total time out in the rain ?  (note - this doesn't actually work, the faster you go the harder water sprays off your wheels and will get Everywhere )

Answer (score 9):

Some road bikes have fender eyelets on the fork and near the rear dropouts (newer eyelets are a bit hidden to preserve the aesthetic on some models). You just buy the fenders and put them on. I'd say most non-race bikes will have them, and ones which are commonly used for commuting or touring will almost definitely have them. Then you buy a set of fenders, and bolt them on.

You can also use clip on mudguards and fenders (e.g. to the seatpost), like the SKS X-board and SKS X-tra dry.

This style clips onto the downtube in lieu of a front fender:

[image]

This style clips onto the seatpost as a rear fender:

[image]

Another style is this (from Planet Bike):

[image]

These don't provide all the benefits of a proper fender (e.g. protecting the drivetrain) but block some of the mud and water and can be mounted on any bike, even a mountain bike:

[image]

Finally, some people just get wet and dirty or don't take their road bikes out in the rain. Note that road bikes generally don't throw up as much crud up as mountain bikes since their tires are smaller.

My road bike has a SKS X-tra Dry seatpost rear fender, and the front is just plain. It uses 700x28 tires, and I find that the front doesn't throw all that much up that I care about it too much. The rear is pretty well covered by the seatpost fender, so I don't have skunk stripe.

Comment: Two of the three bikes pictured are definitely not road bikes. :-)

Comment: +1 For the skunk stripe. I didn't know *normal* had a name :-)

Comment: @RoboKaren - sure. But I'd have to take pictures of my bike otherwise, and I just can't be bothered.

Comment: Most of those fender options would get you kicked out of a wet club ride due to the rearward spray.

Comment: Note that the last set of fenders shown will do precisely eff all to protect you from spray. Notice how there is a straight line from the rear tyre to the back of the seat that doesn't pass through the fender: water will arc up from the back of the tyre and hit you on the back. And the only thing the front fender is protecting is the steerer tube: notice how any water thrown up even slightly backwards from the front tyre will miss the fender entirely.

Answer (score 6):

This is a big issue here in the UK, where it rains rather a lot. And on the minor roads particularly you don't just get wet, but covered in mud, de-icing salt and other gunk - not great for you or your bike. 
Fortunately at least some manufacturers are waking up to the fact that mudguard mounts on road bikes are a really good idea. Some such as the Specialized Roubaix, use very discreet "hidden" mounts that are almost invisible when mudguards are not attached. The Focus Paralane even comes with a set of 'guards included:

[image: Focus Paralane]

For bikes without dedicated mounts there are two main options:
SKS Raceblade long
[image: SKS Raceblade long]

Crud Roadracer Mk3
[image: Crud Roadracer Mk3]

You will need to make sure there is enough frame clearance to fit them.

So to answer your question - you don't have to!

Comment: +1 for the examples on fenders for (road) bikes whitout mounting points for them.

Answer (score 2):

For mechanical reasons, my wet-day bikes are both unavailable, so today I rode to work on my nice road bike.  It has an "ass-saver" but nothing more.  The rain was torrential.

**I got wet**.  I got so wet my shoes had puddles inside them.  My work pants were so dirty with road grime that they looked like I'd had a fall.
My gloves ran water like a tap if I made a fist with one hand.  My under-thighs caught a lot of spray water from the rear wheel resulting in potential chafing.  
 There was road dirt under the saddle, and all round the seat post.  The rim brake tracks looked like a desert, and worked like sandpaper any time I braked, so there was more coasting to a stop than normal.

Once at work, I had a **hot shower** and changed into **spare clothes and shoes** I keep at work.  I also wrung out my clothes in the shower, removing the worst of the water.

Over the course of 8 hours, most of my clothes dried well enough.  The gloves were the wettest part at noon, so I put them in a warm for the afternoon and they still didn't dry fully.  Shoes also were not perfectly dry but fresh socks helped.

At home that night, I put all the wet clothes into the wash, the gloves and shoes needed for tomorrow go in a warm spot to dry.

One day of wet riding is not a big deal as long as you're prepared.
A week of it, or several months of winter is harder to deal with.

---

In lieu of mudguards, you can wear overtrousers and a waterproof parka.  However I find that they don't breathe very well and I get "parboiled" in sweat.

Good overshoes help a lot - the neoprene ones are fine in the cold but useless in the wet.  Rubber overshoes, or ride in gumboots works better in the rain.

Gloves are a mixed bag - thin enough to feel means not waterproof or warm.  Thick enough to be warm, and waterproof both mean poor sensitivity. Both warm and waterproof feels like wearing a chicken on each hand.

---

Additionally, mudguards/fenders keep the road grime off your chain and BB by fully wrapping the rear wheel's top half.  If you don't have guards and ride a lot of roads in the wet, you'll end up doing chain/transmission/derailleur servicing more frequently.  3/8 coverage front and 1/2 coverage rear guards help a lot.

Comment: +1 for that last point. There isn't much rain where I live but full size fenders still *greatly* reduce the mess that builds up on my drivetrain over time.

Answer (score 1):

*"When one drives on a wet road then you get smashed by water and your clothes get dirty."*

Indeed, but those are dedicated sports clothes. One has to change them and get a shower at work even when everything is warm and dry. And when one just go for a casual ride, one should wash them immediately afterwards. It is like underwear, you better do not put it on twice, else you can get saddle sores.

To be honest, I think twice about going for a ride on wet roads, but here they get dry very fast (less than an hour). The choice is rather: can I go off-road (gravel bike) or do I have to stay on the roads?

If I get surprised by rain on the trip, then I get wet from water from all directions (with or without a pocket jacket) and a fender would not save it. I usually ride alone so I also do not have to think about the rider behind me. But this is the biggest reason for a fender, in my opinion - to allow another rider to follow you closely without being in a constant spray of water.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I bought these flimsy plastic fenders that I can snap on within a couple of seconds if I need to.
[image: photo of the fender: The fender is black, attached directly below the saddle (at the height of the rails) and sticks out behind the saddle about half as far as the saddle is long (dimensions are approximately 15cm long by 5cm wide).]

Here you can see how bendy and flimsy they are. They don't offer great protection and I wouldn't recommend them as a permanent solution, but if you want to use your road bike for the occasional trip to the bakery, etc. these might be useful.
[image: Same view of the fender as above, with a hand twisting it slightly to show its thickness and flexibility.]

One tip: I would cut the part that attaches to the seat a little shorter as mine kept rubbing on my pants and it ripped a hole in my pants after a couple of rides.

I bought mine [here](https://www.riesel-bike.com/en/bike/mudguards/rear-xl/rit-ze-l-stealth), but you can get them from many other sites as well, e.g. [ass-savers.com](https://ass-savers.com/)

Comment: These are the ass-savers I mentioned in my answer - they're better than nothing, but I find the back/underside of my thighs get wet from water thrown off the back tyre, but slightly sideways.  I'd call them 20% of a good fender/mudguard, but they're very aero :)

Answer (score -1):

Not everyone will agree with this but here's goes...
Riding, for me, is a means to get out of the sanitized daily grind and thus rain, mud dirt are all welcome. 
Fenders are ugly and if I can avoid them, I always choose to.

Comment: It's a fair point but I think most people would say that this applies more to mountain biking than road biking.

Answer (score -1):

I ride to work. I ride to sports ground. I ride to supermarket. I rode to school. When did I realize I need a fender? When I was late for school I rode through rain and a forest at full speed. Luckily, I was wearing my waterproof jacket and was carrying my water resistant backpack

Comment: So your answer to "how to people ride without fenders?" is "fast, wearing a waterproof jacket and backpack"   ?   Might need to use [edit] to show more, like how you deal with wet pants.  Do you sit on your jacket's tail ?